# torch.cuda.OutOfMemoryError: CUDA out of memory.Tried to allocate 338.00 MiB(GPU 0; 8.00 GiB total capacity; 7.10 GiB already allocated; 0 bytes free

Tags: pytorch, out-of-memory, pytorch-dataloader

I am working on a cuda based jupyter notebook on VScode with a model to convert LR(Low Resolution) images into HR(High Resolution).

Facing the error:
torch.cuda.OutOfMemoryError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 338.00 MiB (GPU 0; 8.00 GiB total capacity; 7.10 GiB already allocated; 0 bytes free; 7.26 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch) If reserved memory is >> allocated memory try setting max_split_size_mb to avoid fragmentation.  See documentation for Memory Management and PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF

Even tried a small input LR image of size 40x40 and HR image of size 120x120 and batch_size=1 ..still facing same error.
Please anyone help.

Complete log of error is:

```
23-06-07 15:40:53.046 - INFO: Start training from epoch: 0, iter: 0
c:\Users\samsung\anaconda3\envs\torch_env\Lib\site- 
packages\torch\optim\lr_scheduler.py:437: UserWarning: To get the last learning rate 
computed by the scheduler, please use `get_last_lr()`.
  warnings.warn("To get the last learning rate computed by the scheduler, "
 23-06-07 15:40:56.722 - INFO: <epoch:  0, iter:       1, lr:1.000e-04> l_g_pix: 
5.7027e- 
   03 l_g_fea: 1.7235e+00 l_g_gan: 3.6864e-03 l_g_pix_grad_branch: 5.9234e-02 l_d_real: 
6.5088e-01 l_d_fake: 6.5088e-01 l_d_real_grad: 1.1526e+00 l_d_fake_grad: 1.1526e+00 
D_real: -3.4521e-02 D_fake: -1.2092e-01 D_real_grad: -7.2899e-01 D_fake_grad: 4.4083e-02 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\SobeldD\code\train.py", line 193, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:\SobeldD\code\train.py", line 143, in main
    model.test()
  File "D:\SobeldD\code\models\SPSR_model.py", line 393, in test
    self.fake_H_branch, self.fake_H, self.grad_LR = self.netG(self.var_L)
                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\samsung\anaconda3\envs\torch_env\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\samsung\anaconda3\envs\torch_env\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\parallel\data_parallel.py", line 169, in forward
return self.module(*inputs[0], **kwargs[0])
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\samsung\anaconda3\envs\torch_env\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 File "D:\SobeldD\code\models\modules\architecture.py", line 195, in forward
x_f_cat = self.f_block(x_f_cat)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\samsung\anaconda3\envs\torch_env\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\SobeldD\code\models\modules\block.py", line 232, in forward
  out = self.RDB1(x)
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\samsung\anaconda3\envs\torch_env\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\SobeldD\code\models\modules\block.py", line 210, in forward
x4 = self.conv4(torch.cat((x, x1, x2, x3), 1))
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\samsung\anaconda3\envs\torch_env\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\samsung\anaconda3\envs\torch_env\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\container.py", line 217, in forward
input = module(input)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\samsung\anaconda3\envs\torch_env\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\samsung\anaconda3\envs\torch_env\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\conv.py", line 463, in forward
return self._conv_forward(input, self.weight, self.bias)
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\samsung\anaconda3\envs\torch_env\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\conv.py", line 459, in _conv_forward
return F.conv2d(input, weight, bias, self.stride,
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
torch.cuda.OutOfMemoryError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 338.00 MiB (GPU 0; 8.00 GiB total capacity; 7.10 GiB already allocated; 0 bytes free; 7.26 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch) If reserved memory is >> allocated memory try setting max_split_size_mb to avoid fragmentation.  See documentation for Memory Management and PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF
```